# Bootstrap non-responsive side by side images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code which displays two images (both are about 350px wide). Now they are displayed in a sidebar which is a set 400px wide on a desktop/tablet (col-lg, col-md, col-sm) but is 100% wide on an col-xs screen. col-xs kicks in at <768px so initially I want both of these images to be side by side but once they get cramped for space and get close to touching I want them to go back to above/below. Currently once it goes below about 700px the right image just starts overlapping the left.

```
<div class="market-img col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
  <img src="$Image1.URL" />
</div>
<div class="market-img col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
  <img src="$Image2.URL" />
</div>
```

I don't want them to be img-responsive because they stay side by side on the small screen and it gets to a point where you can't see them very well. How do I go about forcing the images to go back to above/below?

Comment: please create a fiddle describing your issue...

Answer (score 0):

You have your class declarations backwards.

```
col-sm-12 col-xs-6
```

should be

```
col-sm-6 col-xs-12
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/dez91rvs/))